# Android emulator with snapshot option not working

Tags: android-emulator, macos

I create an android device with configuration:

1. API Level 19 (4.4.2)
2. CPU : ARM(armeabi-v7a)
3. Emulator option :Snapshot Enable .

For the first time the device load takes approx 3 mins. After that loading the device with snapshot takes 20 sec. But I found that I cannot access the device through adb or through GUI. I think this is a bug. Any way to resolve this?
I tried loading android device earlier also with snapshot but in windows system presently my emulator is setup on a mac machine.

Comment: Have you tried restarting the adb server?